# How to fix Fatal error: Call to undefined function, after updating Drupal core?

Tags: updating

I was updating my site to the new 7.41 release. I did the following as usual:

1. Made a backup of files & database
2. Put site in maintenance mode
3. Deleted all files except the Sites folder
4. Uploaded all new folders (excluding Sites)
5. Attempted to update database

Once I did this I got the following error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function ctools_include() in /home/cprids/public_html/sites/all/modules/geofield/geofield.install on line 14

This error is on every page, including the backend, so I'm completely locked out!

So I tried uploading my backup but still have the same error! I've emptied all the cache tables in my database as suggested in another similar discussion but have had zero luck. Any ideas on how to fix this would be really appreciated.

Comment: Can you run `drush` commands on that environment? Can you double check that `ctools` module in still there and enabled?

Comment: Try temporary renaming `geofield` folder into `geofield2`, refresh the page and see if that would help.

Comment: I don't use drush so couldn't tell you if it works I'm afraid. I cant access anything though, every page (including CMS) is down.

Comment: Changing to geofield2 just changed the error name to match it :(

Comment: Then temporary try to rename `geofield.install` file into `geofield.install.bak` and see if that helps.